# how to prove that the segment $IF=HF+GF$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, quadrilateral

> $AE$ and $CD$ are the angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$. $F$ is an arbitrary point on line $DE$. Prove that $GF+HF=IF$.

I noticed $3$ cyclic quadrilaterals. Any ideas.
Here is the picture[image]

Comment: I don't agree to close a puzzling question where the asker has taken time to draw a nice figure ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider Trilinear Coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) first in the case where $F$ is inside triangle $ABC$.

$D$ and $E$, being feet of angle bissectors, have resp. trilinear coord. $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$. Therefore, the trilinear equation of straight line $DE$ is:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&x\\1&1&y\\0&1&z\end{vmatrix}=0 \ \ \iff \ \ x-y+z=0\tag{0}$$

Interpreting $(x=FG,y=FH,z=FI)$, we get:

$$FG+FI-FH=0\tag{1}$$

(**which is not the given relationship !**)

Now, if $F$ is not inside triangle $ABC$, here are the other cases:

- In the case depicted in the given figure ($F$ "just outside" $[DE]$ on the side of $E$), only one of the trilinear coordinates, $FG$, undergoes a sign change ; therefore (1) becomes:

$$\color{red}{-}FG+FI-FH=0\tag{2}$$

which amounts to **the given relationship**, this time !

If, in the case of the given figure, $F$ is far away, a second sign change occurs, now for signed distance $FH$, transforming (2) into  :

$$-FG+FI\color{red}{+}FH=0\tag{3}$$

which is a third formula.

- if, on the contrary, $F$ is outside of line segment $[D,E]$ but on the side of $D$, we have to change $FI$ into its opposite in (1), giving back relationship (3).

Remark about relationship (0): we have obtained it by working up to a multiplicative constant ; this is unimportant because we deal with relationships having a zero in their right-hand side.

Comment: Could you explain to me how the relation and the how matrix will change when $F$ is inside the segment $DE$ and to the left side of $DE$? It seems some negative signs need to be added but I am confused about the rule of the signs.

Comment: The case where $F$ is inside line segment [DE] is without problem, because trilinear coordinates are all positive in this case, therefore are the same as (positive) distances to the sides. For the other cases, I have to add an Edit to my answer. It will be done shortly

Comment: In the process of writing this edit, I realized that the relationship you give is valid only on a certain portion of line (DE), but must be replaced by other (cousin) relationships for other parts of the line... This explains why you were confused about the sign management...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It all makes sense to me now.

Comment: Could you tell the origin of the problem ?

Comment: This is most natural approach if you know trilinear coordinates.

Comment: @JeanMarie, is there a general rule to know if a given distance undergoes a sign change? With barycentric coordinates it is easy to deduce what the sign of a given area will be, but here ...

Comment: @Dr. Mathva: it is the same as for barycentric coordinates (see the def. in the Wikipedia article): iwe deal with _signed_ distances: when you cross one side, the corresponding trilinear coordinate undergoes a sign change.